# How to delete duplicate files using filecmp?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As you can see my code. Forgive me if I didn't ask my question properly. My problem is that this code gives me an error.
This my code. I have same pictures  in `F:\\filetestpython` with different name. I copied all .JPG pictures, but when I run this program I get this error message.

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonBasics\Scripts\python.exe \n"C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/pythonBasics/File Handling/removing duplicate files with filecmp.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonBasics\File Handling\removing duplicate files with filecmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    if filecmp.cmp('2.JPG',file):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\filecmp.py", line 52, in cmp
    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '2.JPG'
2 - Copy (2).JPG

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have all .JPG pictures in one folder. Now I want to delete duplicate pictures from this folder. How can I do that?

```
import os
import filecmp

files = os.listdir('F:\\filetestpython')
for file in files:
    if file != '2.JPG':
        if filecmp.cmp('2.JPG',file):
            os.remove(file)
```

Comment: The error is coming from the `if filecmp.cmp('2.JPG',file):` line. My guess is you need to specify the ull path, as the current working directry of the script isn't `F:\\filetestpython`. Use `if filecmp.cmp('F:\\filetestpython\\2.JPG',file):` instead and see if it works.

Comment: You are passing bare filenames to `filecmp.cmp()`, so it's looking for them in the current working directory - not the `F:\filetestpython` directory where the files are actually located.  You need to use full pathnames here, to specify exactly where the files are found - `os.path.join()` is one way to make a full pathname given a directory and filename.

Comment: This is very much the wrong tool for the job. There are existing 3rd-party tools that do this job well, and they have a lot of optimizations (like looking at sizes -- any file that's unique in having its size is guaranteed to be unique so there's no need to compare or hash it; and hashing headers and footers and comparing against them, and only looking at file bodies when there's otherwise no way to distinguish). This is a domain where a lot of people have already put work into building highly optimized and well-tested tools; it doesn't make sense to roll your own.

Comment: `filecmp` _does_ do a good job of pairwise comparisons, but when you have more than just two files, pairwise comparisons aren't the right thing for the job.

Comment: Thank to all. Jasonnarper your suggestion is very important. And i did that.